# I can Download this Apk in your localhost but after deyploy its showing 404 not found in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, localhost, apk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPSJF.png)

I am adding an external app (apk file)in my react public folder and making a downloading button in react app it's working in localhost but on button click, I am able to download but the same thing is not after deploy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code (and errors if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].